# Actualizar imagen de un listview actualiza indice incorrecto

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Necesito actualizar la imagen de cada posición de mi `listview`, el problema es que hasta el momento actualiza la imagen, pero del indice incorrecto,en la captura de pantalla de mas abajo se muestran 2 botones, para 2 imágenes respectivamente, el problema actual es que se actualiza la segunda imagen apretando los 2 botones, me explico, si presiono el primer botón, se actualiza la segunda imagen y si apretó el segundo botón, se vuelve a actualizar la segunda imagen, por ende el primer botón, no cambia la primera imagen, a continuación dejo el código que utilizando:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewclientes, null);
            holder = new CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder();

            holder.publicidadboton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadboton);
            holder.publicidadimagen = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadimagen);


            final RowItemPublicidad row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.publicidadimagen.setImageResource(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());
            holder.publicidadboton.setText(row_pos.getBoton());

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.publicidadboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position==0){
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda1").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else if(position==1) {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid() + "tienda2").withHint(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0).bitmap();
                    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

[image: al apretar el boton de arriba, me actualiza la imagen de abajo]

Comment: Dame un ejemplo de que obtiene  getFotoPublicidad() ? es un url o un int? @zhet

Comment: un array desde el value con una foto desde un drawable

Comment: Si tiene un array no se puede utilizar, te sugiero agregar que es lo que obtiene o de donde lo obtiene y el LogCat

Answer (score -1):

Recuerda que [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) recibe un entero como parametro que es el id de un recurso dentro del proyecto.

Si lo que intentas cargar es una url debes cambiar a:

```
  //   holder.publicidadimagen.setImageResource(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());    
    URL url = new URL(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

---

Dentro del `Adapter`, específicamente el método `getView()`, la vista se esta creando o reutilizando y lo único que debe cambiar son sus propiedades, debes sacar afuera del if el cambio de propiedades en las vistas.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewclientes, null);
            holder = new CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder();

            holder.publicidadboton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadboton);
            holder.publicidadimagen = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.publicidadimagen);


           /* RowItemPublicidad row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
holder.publicidadimagen.setImageResource(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());
            holder.publicidadboton.setText(row_pos.getBoton());*/

            holder.publicidadboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(position==0){
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(user.getUid()+"tienda1").bitmap();

                        holder.publicidadimagen.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    }else {
                        TastyToast.makeText(v.getContext(),"segundo boton",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,TastyToast.SUCCESS).show();
                    }
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomAdapterPublicidad.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


            // Aquí cambia las propiedades de las vistas en el Adapter:
            RowItemPublicidad row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
             holder.publicidadimagen.setImageResource(row_pos.getFotoPublicidad());
            holder.publicidadboton.setText(row_pos.getBoton());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: lo que intento cargar es un codigo qr, utilizando esta libreria https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen, el bitmap que se genera lo quiero cambiar por la foto

Comment: en este caso no que deberia agregar al logcat, he probado generando el mismo bitmap en otro imageview y se muestra correctamente, el problema que tengo, es que la imagen no se actualiza, independiente si es un bitmap o algun drawable.

Comment: =P eso que dices es importante! "la imagen no se actualiza", se cual es el problema agrego respuesta!, listo!

Comment: sigue sin actualizar, logre que se actualize la imagen, agregando un  notifyDataSetChanged() al final, pero el problema que tengo ahora es que se actualize el indice 1 y no el 0, actualizare mi codigo

Comment: agregue una foto para ejemplificar aun mas el nuevo problema, ademas que actualize el codigo

Comment: te comenté era afuera del if el código para cambiar las propiedades de los contenedores pero veo que sigué dentro.

Comment: probé modificando el código tal como lo plantaste, pero seguia sin actualizar la foto, en el codigo que actualize, la foto cambia, pero en el indice incorrecto

Comment: Alguna explicación para el -1 ?

Comment: -1? en ninguna parte del codigo hay un -1